# Replace outrange values refer to another dataframe for each row in r

Tags: r, if-statement

I post this question to improve my current method. Thanks for helping me!

I have two dataframes.

**Data A** is my measurements:

```
           site 1   site 2  site 3  site 4  site 5  site 6  site 7
1/1/2020    76       44     51        1     18        42     69 
1/2/2020    80       55     52        30    17        38     12 
1/3/2020    36       60     45        44    23        86      4 
1/4/2020    6        73     87        15    96        56     22 
1/5/2020    100      71     58        69    42        11     69 
1/6/2020    6        92     48        73    31        45     89 
1/7/2020    46       52     43        90    2         20      8 
1/8/2020    83       32     23        12    80        64     79 
1/9/2020    63       25     74        79    17        29     88 
1/10/2020   91       53     41        11    29        48     67 
1/11/2020   82       3      32        56    56        61     35 
1/12/2020   55       66     69        88    75        78     88 
1/13/2020   75       52     74        78    30        17     41 
1/14/2020   43       72     24        85    10        75     32
```

**Data B** is my range data. The range(min, max) is **NOT** calculated from Data A.

```
           min  max
1/1/2020    6   60
1/2/2020   10   70
1/3/2020    5   90
1/4/2020    4   100
1/5/2020    10  100
1/6/2020    3   88
1/7/2020    8   99
1/8/2020    8   101
1/9/2020    7   83
1/10/2020   4   97
1/11/2020   5   89
1/12/2020   9   96
1/13/2020   11  85
1/14/2020   5  103
```

I want to truncate the **Data A** refer to **Data B**. Replace outrange value to the min and max values in **Data B**.

This is what I have tried.

```
for (i in 1: 14){
  
  for (j in 1:7){
  
  if (A[i, j]< B[i,1]) {
    
    A[i,j]<-B[i,1]
    
  }
  
  else if (A[i, j]> B[i,2]) {
    
    A[i,j]<-B[i,2]
    
  }
  
  }
  
}
```

14 is the row numbers in A. 7 is the column numbers in A. Row numbers of A nad B are the same.

I have a very large amount of data.  Could anyone tell me a faster approach?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the two datasets based on dates and use `pmin` and `pmax` to keep the data in range within each date.

```
library(dplyr)

A %>%
  rownames_to_column('Date') %>%
  inner_join(B %>% rownames_to_column('Date'), by = 'Date') %>%
  mutate(across(site1:site7, ~pmin(pmax(., min), max)))

#        Date site1 site2 site3 site4 site5 site6 site7 min max
#1   1/1/2020    60    44    51     6    18    42    60   6  60
#2   1/2/2020    70    55    52    30    17    38    12  10  70
#3   1/3/2020    36    60    45    44    23    86     5   5  90
#4   1/4/2020     6    73    87    15    96    56    22   4 100
#5   1/5/2020   100    71    58    69    42    11    69  10 100
#6   1/6/2020     6    88    48    73    31    45    88   3  88
#7   1/7/2020    46    52    43    90     8    20     8   8  99
#8   1/8/2020    83    32    23    12    80    64    79   8 101
#9   1/9/2020    63    25    74    79    17    29    83   7  83
#10 1/10/2020    91    53    41    11    29    48    67   4  97
#11 1/11/2020    82     5    32    56    56    61    35   5  89
#12 1/12/2020    55    66    69    88    75    78    88   9  96
#13 1/13/2020    75    52    74    78    30    17    41  11  85
#14 1/14/2020    43    72    24    85    10    75    32   5 103
```

**data**

```
A <- structure(list(site1 = c(76L, 80L, 36L, 6L, 100L, 6L, 46L, 83L, 
63L, 91L, 82L, 55L, 75L, 43L), site2 = c(44L, 55L, 60L, 73L, 
71L, 92L, 52L, 32L, 25L, 53L, 3L, 66L, 52L, 72L), site3 = c(51L, 
52L, 45L, 87L, 58L, 48L, 43L, 23L, 74L, 41L, 32L, 69L, 74L, 24L
), site4 = c(1L, 30L, 44L, 15L, 69L, 73L, 90L, 12L, 79L, 11L, 
56L, 88L, 78L, 85L), site5 = c(18L, 17L, 23L, 96L, 42L, 31L, 
2L, 80L, 17L, 29L, 56L, 75L, 30L, 10L), site6 = c(42L, 38L, 86L, 
56L, 11L, 45L, 20L, 64L, 29L, 48L, 61L, 78L, 17L, 75L), site7 = c(69L, 
12L, 4L, 22L, 69L, 89L, 8L, 79L, 88L, 67L, 35L, 88L, 41L, 32L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1/1/2020", "1/2/2020", 
"1/3/2020", "1/4/2020", "1/5/2020", "1/6/2020", "1/7/2020", "1/8/2020", 
"1/9/2020", "1/10/2020", "1/11/2020", "1/12/2020", "1/13/2020", 
"1/14/2020"))

B <- structure(list(min = c(6L, 10L, 5L, 4L, 10L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 
4L, 5L, 9L, 11L, 5L), max = c(60L, 70L, 90L, 100L, 100L, 88L, 
99L, 101L, 83L, 97L, 89L, 96L, 85L, 103L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1/1/2020", "1/2/2020", "1/3/2020", "1/4/2020", "1/5/2020", 
"1/6/2020", "1/7/2020", "1/8/2020", "1/9/2020", "1/10/2020", "1/11/2020",
 "1/12/2020", "1/13/2020", "1/14/2020"))
```